# Fade text using jQuery/Javascript with infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently building a website and want to fade several words at certain interval and certain fading time with infinite loop. This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: text fade]

I've come up with this but don't know how to extend the time each word is displayed independently of fading time, so that it looks like on gif.

```js
var text = ['fade1', 'fade2', 'fade3'];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("fade");
function change() {
  jQuery(elem).fadeTo(1400, 0, function() {
    this.innerHTML = text[counter];
    counter = ++counter % text.length;
    jQuery(this).fadeTo(1400, 1, change)
  })
}
change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text <span id="fade"></span></p>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Hi Benua, your question sounds like you expect us to write your code for you. That's not how Stack Overflow works. Please try to code it yourself first, when you run into problems, post your code and ask specific questions about it. People will be glad to help you.

Comment: Hi, sorry I updated my question

Comment: @PatrickHund looks like it's been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jQuery.delay`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) to pause the code for a certain number of milliseconds before moving to the next one:

```js
var timeOnEachText = 2000; // Milliseconds to spend on each before moving to next

var text = ['fade1', 'fade2', 'fade3'];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("fade");
function change() {
  jQuery(elem).delay(timeOnEachText).fadeTo(1400, 0, function() {
    this.innerHTML = text[counter];
    counter = ++counter % text.length;
    jQuery(this).fadeTo(1400, 1, change)
  })
}
change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text <span id="fade"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the interval, you could convert your text array to an array-object and add some values to it, like this:

```js
var text = [
  {
    text: 'fade1',
    fadeIn: 1000,
    fadeOut: 500,
    timeout: 100,
  },
  {
    text: 'fade2',
    fadeIn: 1100,
    fadeOut: 1500,
    timeout: 1000,
  },
  {
    text: 'fade3',
    fadeIn: 500,
    fadeOut: 300,
    timeout: 3000,
  }
];
var counter = 0;
var fadeTimeout = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("fade");
function change() {
  var currentTextItem = text[counter];
  setTimeout( () => {
    jQuery(elem).fadeTo(currentTextItem.fadeIn, 0, function() {
      this.innerHTML = currentTextItem.text;
      counter = ++counter % text.length;
      jQuery(this).fadeTo(currentTextItem.fadeOut, 1, change)
    });
    
    // Set new timeout because in this set up the next item
    // controls the timeout of the previous one.
    fadeTimeout = currentTextItem.timeout;
  }, fadeTimeout );
}
change()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text <span id="fade">initial text</span></p>
```

Comment: Hi, I meant how to increase the waiting time between switching of words so that it works as on gif I provided. Now it flickers evenly which makes it hard to read. Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: I updated my answer, adding a setTimeout will do the trick here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll work for you but have you thought about using @keyframes and just hiding showing the images at different intervals? If you know what the data is before hand and the number of images, you can set up key frames and it'll display much nicer.